# org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver ClassNotFoundException while running junit test for a method

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am using one method which return me a datasource. The method is as below:

```
public static DataSource getDataSource(){
        String url;
        //url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:"+filePath;
        url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:/EclipseWorskpace/ew-pg/lmexadapter/hsqldb-example/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/data/db/hsqldb.jar";
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setUsername("SA");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("password");
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
        basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$ URL is : " + url);
        return basicDataSource;
    }
```

And I am calling these method from dao. and with all this I am using ibatis for my OR mapping. When I run my test case by junit test it is giving me a exception:

```
" org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1259)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1192)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:884)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:213)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1253)
    ... 39 more
"
```

Comment: @Jigar: I'd rather see them post too much stacktrace than too little.

Answer (score 10):

By downloading and adding *HSQLDB* jar in class path from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/hsqldb/hsqldb/)

Comment: i cannot add the jar in my classpath apart from this if you have a other suggestion to resolve this

Comment: why ??, *no other solution exist*

Comment: @Chitresh: since that's the only correct solution, you're out of luck.

Comment: hi i can't add jar in my classpath, if you have a other suggestion except this plz tell me i had tried adding jar in my tomcat server lib, but it is not getting from there also

Comment: `i had tried adding jar in my tomcat server lib,` && `hi i can't add jar in my classpath,` will return false.  it should work. retry putting the jar in `common\lib`

Comment: hi i add the jar in my project build path and the previous problem was solved but i got a new exception the exception is:

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers here were right, and wrong.

The HSQLDB jar needs added to the classpath. The problem is in the previous answers the questioner was being pointed at old versions of the project that did not have the class they were looking for. The class which was not found is only in version 2 of HSQLDB, available from  http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/hsqldb/hsqldb_2_3/

Comment: Thanks, That was lucky you putting that answer in yesterday!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using maven try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you have already downloaded the  HSQLDB jar file and properly installed then I would check the classpath.

Comment: if have to do without adding it into a classpath then how i can do. i got one solution to add a jar in my tomcat lib, but it is also giving me a same exception. do you have any idea how to reslove this

Comment: Most probably you should add to your build path. I am assuming that you are using Eclipse, then right click into your project, click properties and then add it to your build path. Where did you put your jar file? and how? You can drag and drop the file into a lib directory of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Grab:

```
@Grab('org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.3')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
```

more info: http://groovy-lang.org/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

Try following dependency config in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
   <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
   <classifier>jdk8</classifier>
   <version>2.6.1</version>        
</dependency>
```

For me adding that classifier line solved an issue.
Please see below recommendation in hsqldb repo.
https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1644/